# How do i know if minecraft is bedrock or beta edition on android?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I noticed that the bedrock edition and the beta edition are different in many ways but I don't understand how

And I don't know if mine is a beta or bedrock edition and if so does matter for playing online or anything else

Comment: What do you mean with "beta edition"? [Here](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Minecraft#Editions) is a list of all Minecraft "editions", none of them is called "beta". "beta" is a label for program versions that aren't ready for an official release yet, like the Minecraft versions before 1.0 (until 2011) or the snapshots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are comparing with Minecraft: Pocket Edition, which is now discontinued, and has been replaced with bedrock edition. Pocket Edition is no longer currently usable, so I believe you should have Bedrock edition.

You can look at the bottom right of the menu screen. The latest version is currently 1.8.0.
Seeing anything lower than 1.0.0 mean you are on Pocket Edition.

There are many differences, ranging from programming language to optimization. Bedrock edition is far superior, including many more features, and usability across platforms.